# Como descobrir o número de registros de um model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-record

Criei um scaffold chamado livro e queria criar um método para fazer a contagem de quantos cadastros de livros existem no meu banco de dados e usar esse resultado no controller de outro scaffold, chamado quadro de avisos, onde mostrará o total de livros, o total de empréstimos e empréstimos a vencer

Obs.: Aprendendo Rails e apanhando um pouco com a sintaxe.

Comment: ja resolvi o problema foi bem simples assim:    dentro do model do quadro de avisos coloquei   Livro.count  e na view fiz <%= Livro.count %>

Comment: Correto Diego: <%= Livro.count %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Os modelos do Active Record possuem o método [`#count`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-count), que pode ser usado da seguinte forma:

```
Book.count
# SELECT COUNT(*) FROM books
=> 10
```

Você pode até aplicar condições à query, dessa forma:

```
Book.where(status: :active).count
# SELECT COUNT(*) FROM books WHERE books.status = 1
=> 5
```

Para usar na view você pode interpolar utilizando o [ERB](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html):

```
<p>Existem <%= Book.count %> livros disponíveis.
```

Mas é recomendado utilizar lógicas como essa diretamente na view, então você pode utilizar uma [variável de instância](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/instancevars.html) na action:

```
def index
  @book_count = Book.count
end
```

e na view ficaria:

```
<p>Existem <%= @book_count %> livros disponíveis.
```